# Converting an array of morphemes to a sentence in Ruby

Tags: ruby, nlp

I want to convert an array of morphemes produced by a [PTB-style](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/tokenization.html) tokenizer:

```
["The", "house", "is", "n't", "on", "fire", "."]
```

To a sentence:

```
"The house isn't on fire."
```

What is a sensible way to accomplish this?

Comment: Apostrophe is not punctuation. At least historically, it represents some omitted letters, and is a part of a word. It does not make sense to split a word there. Furthermore, how would you tell when you want to join one side `students' books` or both sides `one's book`?

Comment: I'm not sure if you've thought through the requirements. Like sawa said, how will you decide how to treat apostrophes? Also, will you ever use an apostrophe as an open or close quote mark? These symbols require context to know how treat them. It sounds like you need to define a grammar to decide what kinds of tokens can/cannot follow another kind of token.

Comment: How was the array created in the first place? What types of punctuation (or other) symbols may appear in it? If you don't explain these things, how can you expect anyone to answer this question?

Comment: @sawa The apostrophe actually is a punctuation mark, even when introducing a possessive (refer to a linguistics textbook). And your "ambiguity" actually isn't one - the apostrophe reduces to the left in the first case because the word ends in `s` and to the left and right in the second case because it is not preceded by an `s` and followed by one of `s`, `t`, `ll`, etc.

Comment: @jogojapan I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Well, FYI, linguistics does not deal with what an apostrophe is. That is a matter of English orthography. Refer to a linguistics textbook. And you wanted us to read your mind and handle appostrophe according to what it is surrounded by. That surely is expecting too much, and it qualifies as making the question not clear.

Comment: @louism Thanks for the edit, and I think this is actually a good question, but I am also a bit confused. According to the page you linked, your tokenizer divides elements that contain an apostrophe into _morphemes_. In this case, the tokenization should be `"is","n't"`, not `"isn","'","t"`.

Comment: @sawa You are a very valuable contributor to this site, but clearly have a deep misunderstanding of linguistics. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=e6qg5g&s=6.

Comment: @jogojapan You are right, I edited again accordingly.

Comment: @louism Since you seem to be implying that you have deeper understanding of linguistics than me, I am now sure that you have a PhD in linguistics. But at the same time, to you, wikipedia is the almighty god. It is never wrong. That seems contradictory to me. How could that happen?

Comment: @sawa Why don't you write a few [NLP tools](https://github.com/louismullie) and then we can discuss this further?

Comment: @louism Why don't YOU do it? Why do I have to do that for you? How much are you willing to pay me?

Comment: @sawa Sorry if my sarcasm wasn't clear enough: if you have a look at my Github page, you will realize why I think I can claim a minimal degree of knowledgeability in NLP.

Comment: @louism So what? How can a person with a knowledge in NLP tokenize a string into `isn`, `"`, and `t`? And, why do I have to do that for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take @sawa's advice on the apostrophe and make your array this:

```
["The", "house", "isn't", "on", "fire", "."]
```

You can get what your looking for (with punctuation support!) with this:

```
def sentence(array)
  str = ""
  array.each_with_index do |w, i|
    case w
    when '.', '!', '?' #Sentence enders, inserts a space too if there are more words.
      str << w
      str << ' ' unless(i == array.length-1)
    when ',', ';' #Inline separators
      str << w
      str << ' '
    when '--' #Dash
      str << ' -- '
    else #It's a word
      str << ' ' unless str[-1] == ' ' || str.length == 0
      str << w
    end
  end
  str
end
```